# Stored Proc: Loop with math

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor, procedure

I need to create a stored procedure - i have very limited knowledge of them however.

Basically it will import data from an existing table, process this data, and then create a new table.

Whats the best method to go about this?

There are several different counters, and values are added to these counters according to another value;

eg:

```
house_name  | person_name
------------+------------
bighouse    |  sam
bighouse    |  sammy
bighouse    |  joe
smlhouse    |  brad
smlhouse    |  kev
```

ie. in this example the counters would have the values of 3 and 2 (3 people in bighouse, 2 in smlhouse) (in my actual work both are 'int' so no problem there).

I've been told to use a Cursor, but am finding it hard to know how to use it!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When I hear 'counters', I tend to thing of SUM, COUNT and ROW_NUMBER functions rather than cursors. Assuming the above example is your imported table, what would your expected new table contain? Surely more than just "bighouse 3 smlhouse 2"?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you wouldn't store "derived" information in a database. It always brings the risk of inconsistencies.

The usual approach would be to add a view:

```
create view house_stats
as
select  house_name
,       count(*) as number_of_people
from    YourTable
group by
        house_name
```

You can use the view in queries as it it were a table.  Because it's in fact a stored calculation, there is no risk of inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

These links will get you started:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql

Answer (score 0):

Your question feels vague to me, but I can give you code for that very specific example.

```
INSERT INTO
  yourResultsTable
SELECT
  house_name,
  COUNT(*)       AS people_per_house
FROM
  yourDataTable
GROUP BY
  house_name
```

This avoids using cursors.  SQL is a set based lanaguage and although T-SQL can do loops you will find the perormance much much worse in the vast majority of cases.

If you have other counters that are momre complex, we can help with those too, but we need to know the structure of your input data, any constraints on that data, the strucutre and constrains of the output data, and examples of the two relate to each other.